# Java spring boot as a windows service alternative

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, microservices

I have multiple spring boot projects that a running on windows server. For now I am deploying each project as a windows service because we cant use docker.

Now I was thinking about to reduce the amount of windows services that I have but not change the microservice architecure.
One alternative is OSGi which seems to be very nice but as I have seen it is not recommend to use spring boot apps with OSGi.
The next alternative I was thinking about was to create my own java "controller app" that then can start/stop the other microservices. So only the "controller app" has to be deployed as a windows service.

Is there a better alternative instead of creating a own "controller app"? Docker would be nice but unfortunately we can´t use it. Or should we maybe try to run our spring boot services with OSGi?

Comment: I would stick with services because when one crashes the rest stays intact because each has its own separate JVM

Comment: If the "controller app" starts the jars with "jar -jar service1.jar" they should run in a seperate JVM too or not? The problem with the windows services is that they have a little overhead. And the main reason is that I already have like 10 services for the core application. And now with the new spring boot services that I need there will be at least 5 new services. And some customers are already wondering why I need so many windows services in compare to other software so I was looking for an alternative to the windows services but with the same features (start/stop/restart...).

Comment: It sounds like you may want to use external tomcat instead of embedded, assuming you're using tomcat. Then one service, tomcat, where you can manage those services

Comment: Valid point. But don't forget that Java service wrappers have checks, restarts and dependency support built in. You would have to create this on your own. If the *amount* of services is the only downside to your current approach in my eyes this doesn't justify a change and you should spend your time on other things